# How to format SQLCMD output

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd

I am using below command line to run a SQL query using SQLCMD

```
sqlcmd -S Server -Q "select top 100 * From people" -d people -t 10
```

The table has 20 columns and when i look at output command line window wraps the text and makes it difficult to read.

I want my results to be displayed the same way it displays in *SQL Server Management Studio* (properly formatted). I am not looking for any grids, but i need all my columns to be displayed in row 1 and the results properly beneath.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Console windows have a fixed width. If there's more text to display in each row than the console width, what do you *expect* the tool to do? It cannot physically display all of the columns in row 1.

Comment: Blegh. I occasionally need to do SQL queries and SQLCMD is horrible if you want output from it because it can only return a single string. I recommend checking out the answer here which pumps a SQL query into a table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509591/creating-a-powershell-connection-string

Answer (score 39):

### Answer

We can set the width of each column.

```
C:/> sqlcmd -S my_server

> :setvar SQLCMDMAXVARTYPEWIDTH 30
> :setvar SQLCMDMAXFIXEDTYPEWIDTH 30
> SELECT * from my_table
> go
```

We can also set it like this: `sqlcmd -S my_server -y 30 -Y 30`.

### Details

SQLCMDMAXVARTYPEWIDTH (`-y`)

> It limits the number of characters that are returned for the large variable length data type

SQLCMDMAXFIXEDTYPEWIDTH (`-Y`)

> Limits the number of characters that are returned for the following data types

Note: setting `-y` has serious performance implications.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility

Comment: Setting `-y` to `0` has serious performance implications.  Other values should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Formatting issues usually pop up due to your console window.
One solution is to output to the file and use notepad/your favorite editor:

```
sqlcmd -S myServer -d myDB -E -Q "select top 100 * From people" 
     -o "output.txt"
```

Comment: While this helps with formatting, make sure you use a proper text editor. Notepad for example still wraps long lines. I use Notepad++ and it displays almost 4000 Character long lines flawlessly.

Comment: This is not possible if you're trying to script.  I'm guessing some type of grep/sed magic is needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I isolated a scalar.

```
sqlcmd -S xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxxx -d MyDb -U myUser -P MyPassword -h -1 -W -Q "set NOCOUNT ON; select a from b where b.id='c'"
```